# Are there downsides to installing node.js with root privileges?

Tags: installation, security, sudo, root, node.js

I'm using the following code to install node:

```
    cd /usr/local/src/
    wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.25/node-v0.10.25.tar.gz
    tar -xvf node-v0.10.25.tar.gz
    cd node-v0.10.25
    ./configure
    make
    make install
        # node.js links to make sudo work right
    ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node
    ln -s /usr/local/lib/node /usr/lib/node
    ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
    ln -s /usr/local/bin/node-waf /usr/bin/node-waf
```

The script requires root privileges, and I'm wondering if that opens up the possibility of any security holes, or anything like that. I want to install node so that all user can use it, but I don't want it to have any root privileges unless the user has them and explicitly uses them (via sudo). Same with installed npm packages.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question about installing as root, but it's safer to run [npm](https://github.com/npm/npm#user-content-permissions-when-using-npm-to-install-other-stuff) as root when installing packages.

> As of version 0.3, it is recommended to run npm as root. This allows npm to change the user identifier to the `nobody` user prior to running any package build or test commands.